# Upload MultiPart file from Android to server(SpringMVC)

Tags: android, spring, spring-mvc, retrofit

If, I'm using Postmam file upload without problems. But, when anroid tries upload file in server, method throws NPE, becouse MultipartFile file = null.

**Android**

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

Call<MediaResponseModel> call = service.uploadImage(requestBody);

call.enqueue(new RetrofitCallback<>(callback));


@POST("/uploadImage")

Call<MediaResponseModel> uploadImage(@Part("file") RequestBody file);
```

**Server**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> imageUpload(@RequestHeader(value = "id") String sessionId,
                                      @RequestParam (value = "file")   MultipartFile file)
```

*ApplicationContext*

```
 <bean id="jsonConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
            <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven >
<mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
</mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to do it on android using HTTP, there are some third party libraries you can use that.

1. [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion)
2. [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Both are good libraries, I have used both in my projects.

Comment: I don't know how this answer was accepted; this doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Retrofit network library , it is the fastest one available

It supports multipart files and its implementation is very simple

http://square.github.io/retrofit/